# How to Align the equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is for a brochure where an equation has to be put beside the circle in an optimal place such that it looks good.

here's the cod

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sexy]{evan}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.2in,bottom=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sexy]{evan}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.text}
\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{62, 97, 127}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{104, 182, 182}
\definecolor{c3}{RGB}{107, 190, 190}
\definecolor{c4}{RGB}{100, 172, 174}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,rotating,picture,lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=,
}
\urlstyle{same} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ordinal}{ord}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}



\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10, 11)
    \scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$}
\end{picture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,font=\sffamily\bfseries]
 \draw[very thick,c4,name path=big arc] ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:285:11)
 coordinate[pos=0.225] (x0);
 \begin{scope}
  \clip ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:285:11) --(current page.north
  east);
  \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=4.55cm]x0) circle (4.55);
  \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=3.4cm]x0) circle (3.4);
  \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=2.25cm]x0) circle (2.25);
  \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x0) arc(-90:30:6.5);
  \draw[very thick,c4] (x0) arc(90:-30:8.75);
  \draw[very thick,c4!50,name path=arc1] (x0) arc(90:-90:4.675);
  \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x0) arc(90:-90:2.875);
  \path[name intersections={of=big arc and arc1,by=x1}];
  \draw[very thick,c4,name path=arc2] (x1) arc(135:-20:4.75);
  \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x1) arc(135:-20:8.75);
  \path[name intersections={of=big arc and arc2,by={aux,x2}}];
  \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x2) arc(180:50:2.25);
 \end{scope} 
 \path[decoration={text along path,text color=c4,
                 raise = -2.8ex,
                 text  along path,
                 %text = {|\sffamily\bfseries|02/18/2019},
                 text align = center,
             },
             decorate
         ] ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:245:11);
 %
 \begin{scope}
  \path[clip,postaction={fill=c3}]
  ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) rectangle ++ (4.2,7.7);
  \fill[c2] ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center)
   ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center)  arc(180:60:2)
    |- ++ (-3,6) --cycle;
  \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
  arc(180:0:2);
  \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
  arc(180:0:2);
  \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
  arc(180:0:2);
  \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=4.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
  arc(180:0:2);
  \fill[white] ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) +(60:2) circle(1.5mm)
  node[above right=2mm]{$\displaystyle\rho=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$};
 \end{scope}
 %
 \fill[c1] ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) rectangle ++ (-12.7,7.7);
 \node[text=white,anchor=west,scale=5,inner sep=0pt] at
 ([xshift=-8cm,yshift=-3.25cm]current page.center) {GLCGM};
 \node[text=white,anchor=west,scale=2.0,inner sep=0pt] at
 ([xshift=-9cm,yshift=-6cm]current page.center) {TFP x THREE STANCHION};
 %
 \draw[gray,line width=5mm] 
 ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-1mm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=1mm]current
 page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the what I get after compiling

[image]

I need to place the equation such that it aligns with the point where all circles are intersecting and also to make it more decorative, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the picture with
`\node [left = of x0] {\scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$}};`

(using also `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`)

[image: a2]

```
\documentclass[letter, 11pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[sexy]{evan}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1.2in,bottom=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[sexy]{evan}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.text}
\definecolor{c1}{RGB}{62, 97, 127}
\definecolor{c2}{RGB}{104, 182, 182}
\definecolor{c3}{RGB}{107, 190, 190}
\definecolor{c4}{RGB}{100, 172, 174}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,rotating,picture,lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=,
}
\urlstyle{same} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ordinal}{ord}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
%   \begin{picture}(10, 11)
%       \scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$} %%% remove <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%   \end{picture}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,font=\sffamily\bfseries]
        \draw[very thick,c4,name path=big arc] ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:285:11)
        coordinate[pos=0.225] (x0);
        \begin{scope}
            \node [left = of x0] {\scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$}};   % added <<<<<<<<<<         
            \clip ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:285:11) --(current page.north
            east);
            \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=4.55cm]x0) circle (4.55);
            \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=3.4cm]x0) circle (3.4);
            \fill[c4!50,opacity=0.25] ([xshift=2.25cm]x0) circle (2.25);
            \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x0) arc(-90:30:6.5);
            \draw[very thick,c4] (x0) arc(90:-30:8.75);
            \draw[very thick,c4!50,name path=arc1] (x0) arc(90:-90:4.675);
            \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x0) arc(90:-90:2.875);
            \path[name intersections={of=big arc and arc1,by=x1}];
            \draw[very thick,c4,name path=arc2] (x1) arc(135:-20:4.75);
            \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x1) arc(135:-20:8.75);
            \path[name intersections={of=big arc and arc2,by={aux,x2}}];
            \draw[very thick,c4!50] (x2) arc(180:50:2.25);
        \end{scope} 
        \path[decoration={text along path,text color=c4,
            raise = -2.8ex,
            text  along path,
            %text = {|\sffamily\bfseries|02/18/2019},
            text align = center,
        },
        decorate
        ] ([xshift=-2mm]current page.north) arc(150:245:11);
        %
        \begin{scope}
            \path[clip,postaction={fill=c3}]
            ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) rectangle ++ (4.2,7.7);
            \fill[c2] ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center)
            ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center)  arc(180:60:2)
            |- ++ (-3,6) --cycle;
            \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
            arc(180:0:2);
            \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
            arc(180:0:2);
            \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
            arc(180:0:2);
            \draw[very thick,c4] ([xshift=4.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) 
            arc(180:0:2);
            \fill[white] ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) +(60:2) circle(1.5mm)
            node[above right=2mm]{$\displaystyle\rho=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$};
        \end{scope}
        %
        \fill[c1] ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-8cm]current page.center) rectangle ++ (-12.7,7.7);
        \node[text=white,anchor=west,scale=5,inner sep=0pt] at
        ([xshift=-8cm,yshift=-3.25cm]current page.center) {GLCGM};
        \node[text=white,anchor=west,scale=2.0,inner sep=0pt] at
        ([xshift=-9cm,yshift=-6cm]current page.center) {TFP x THREE STANCHION};
        %
        \draw[gray,line width=5mm] 
        ([xshift=2mm,yshift=-1mm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=1mm]current
        page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**OPTION**

Suggested by @Edson Marcon, using

```
\node [left = of x0, text= c4] {\scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle e^{i\pi}+1=0$}};
```

[image: f]

Comment: suggestion: make Euler's identity in a shade of green, too.